# Magento2 : Custom Magento extension to display info on success.phtml

Tags: module, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

I am trying to Create my first custom extension. Unfortunately i think that i miss something.

In the magento 2 root directory i have the following files:

> **/app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/registration.php**

```
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Clud7_Skroutz',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **/app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Clud7_Skroutz" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> **app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="clud7" frontName="skroutz">
            <module name="Clud7_Skroutz" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/Block/Success.php**

```
<?php
namespace Clud7\Skroutz\Block;
class Success  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'returned something from custom block.';
    }
}
```

> **app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="Clud7\Skroutz\Block\Success"
               name="clud7.order.success"
               template="Clud7_Skroutz::order/success.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> **app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml**

```
<?php /* @var $block \Clud7\Skroutz\Block\Success */?>
<?php echo __('Custom template file content.'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getSomething(); ?>
```

My module is activated and also my magento 2 is compiled and cache cleaned.
Also static content deployed.

Comment: What you want to do in  success.phtml?

Comment: I want to display order id and to add few javascripts for product feed sale. My problem here is that i am unable even to display a single echo text command.

Comment: For that you can override success.phtml file in your custom theme you don't need to create extension for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You module code is correct. You have to need run command step by step and after `you can place the order to check success page information`.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

**For debug success page:**

Temporarily you can debug checkout success page, to stop the checkout success page redirection after refresh page.

> File path:
>   magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php

`Find the code and comment it:`

> // $session->clearQuote();

See below output of your module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override success.phmtl in to your custom theme. Don't need to create an extension for that

I have override success.phml file on my porto theme as follows

`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/Porto/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phmtl`